# wget url not working, while browser is downloading it properly

Tags: python, url, download, wget

I want to download a 7z file from this url: 'ftp://ftp.mtps.gov.br/pdet/microdados/NOVO%20CAGED/Movimenta%E7%F5es/2020/Junho/CAGEDMOV202001.7z'

If I paste it on a browser, it will download properly. However when I use the wget.download(url, 'caged.7z') method, it throws the following error:

```
<urlopen error ftp error: error_perm('550 The system cannot find the path specified. ')>
```

Anyone knows what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decode the entities ‰20, %e7 and %f5 as curl won't do that for you as browser would ([table](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)).

You can use urllib's `unquote()` for that:

i.e.

```
import urllib.parse

...

url = urllib.parse.unquote(your_url)
```