# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found even though I can go to the link?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import wget   # Downloads files from url

page = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallery_of_sovereign_state_flags")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for flag in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': "image"}):
    src = flag.contents[0]['src']
    src = src.replace("thumb/", "")
    src = "https:" + src
    sep = '.svg'
    fixed_src = src.split(sep, 1)[0] + ".svg"
    print(fixed_src)
    for country in data["Country"]:    # A column containing country names
        if country in fixed_src:
            wget.download(fixed_src, f'flags/{country}.svg')
```

It works for most of the urls generated, but once it reaches "Australia" it returns the urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found. but when I press on the link it redirects me to it and it IS found.

I tried placing an if statement to ignore Australia, but few other urls returned the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problems are mosty likely related to escaped characters in your urls. Browsers know how to resolve them; however it seems that the wget library does not know how to do it, and you have to get rid of the escaped characters yourself.

Try adding `urllib.parse.unquote(fixed_src)` to your code before doing the wget. It resolved the problems with 404's at least for me.

See the difference:

Before unquoting:

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7a/Flag_of_Afghanistan_%282004%E2%80%932021%29.svg
```

After unquoting:

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7a/Flag_of_Afghanistan_(2004–2021).svg
```

Full code below:

```py
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import wget   # Downloads files from url

page = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallery_of_sovereign_state_flags")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for flag in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': "image"}):
    src = flag.contents[0]['src']
    src = src.replace("thumb/", "")
    src = "https:" + src
    sep = '.svg'
    fixed_src = src.split(sep, 1)[0] + ".svg"
    print(fixed_src)
    url_unquoted = urllib.parse.unquote(fixed_src)
    print(url_unquoted)
    for country in data["Country"]:    # A column containing country names
        if country in url_unquoted:
            wget.download(url_unquoted, f'flags/{country}.svg')
```

[Similar problem, found with "python wget fails for url" from Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64449029/wget-url-not-working-while-browser-is-downloading-it-properly)

[urllib documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

Comment: I'm glad that I could help!